# How can one define an array type variable in gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I'm writing a gitlab-ci.yaml script for my pipeline, and trying to define an array of strings variable (simplified version of the code):

```
npm_audit:
  variables:
    PACKAGE-WHITE-LIST: ["package A", "package B"]
  script:
   - npm install audit-ci
   - npx audit-ci -w PACKAGE-WHITE-LIST npm >> audit.log
```

When I run the pipeline, I get a yaml parse failure:
"variables config should be a hash of key value pairs array"

What am I missing here?

Comment: why do you want to create an array ? `PACKAGE-WHITE-LIST: "package A package B"` should work

Comment: @NicolasPepinster when I changed it according to your suggestion I got the following error: /bin/bash: line 75: export: `PACKAGE-WHITE-LIST=extend kue': not a valid identifier

Comment: It's because of the dash in your variable name, please see my answer

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code is not working for some reasons :

- Your variable can't contain [dash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23660)
- You forgot the `$` before your variable name to retrieve its value
- You don't need to create an array

The following definition should work :

```
  npm_audit:
  variables:
    PACKAGE_WHITE_LIST: "package A package B"
  script:
   - npm install audit-ci
   - npx audit-ci -w $PACKAGE_WHITE_LIST npm >> audit.log
```

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that those package names contain spaces cause a problem?

Comment: Are you able to define array variable then?

Comment: @BorislavStoilov Unfortunately, it looks like you can not via Gitlab CI. Really frustrating, but the only 'solution' GL provides really is spaces (which doesn't work with question).

Answer (score 1):

that's what I had to do for similar issue:

```
.image-release-settings:
    images:
    - image1 image2
    - image3 image4
    - image5

release-images:
  script:
  - |
    cat << EOF >images
  - !reference [.image-release-settings, images]
  - |
    EOF
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      if [[ $line == "echo"* ]]; then
        continue  # gitlab's garbage
      fi
      echo $line #seems that's what you need
      for image in $line; do
        echo "image: $image"
      done
    done < images
```

Answer (score 0):

[prog76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2949213/prog76)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77590850/10828860) works perfectly.

I want to give one addendum, that you can filter out the junk data with `grep echo -v` and pipe it further, e.g.

```
.image-release-settings:
    images:
    - image1 image2
    - image3 image4
    - image5

release-images:
  script:
  - |
    cat << EOF | grep echo -v | xargs ...
  - !reference [.image-release-settings, images]
  - |
    EOF
```