# GitLab CI yml check if value is within array at workflow rules

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have to validate a pipeline before triggering it. One criterion of the validation is if a CI/CD variable has one of the accepted values. Is there a way to find if it is matching the correct values?

I tried to create an [array of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57457323/how-can-one-define-an-array-type-variable-in-gitlab-ci) then to [check it in the workflow rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55464100/6357360) but it is not clear from the other questions how to do that.

So it should be looking like this:

```
#WARNING: invalid yml!
variables:
  ValidValues: ["Value1", "Value2", "SomeOtherValue"]

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: ValidValues contains $GivenValue
      when: always
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching on this issue, I found that I can add the [allowed values to a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524993/regular-expression-that-checks-for-2-specific-words) on which I can check at the workflow rules. In the end it looks like this:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $GivenValue =~ /\b(Value1|Value2|SomeOtherValue)\b/
      when: always
    - when: never
```

Unfortunately I did not found a solution on my initial approach (adding the allowed values to an array, then looking for them) but this works as well.